# Drive API own files in folder created by my application

Tags: java, rest, google-drive-api

I am looking at ways to only get required access to a user's google drive. We have a web application which links to user's drive and then we provide search facilities to user through various bot platforms based on data they have kept in their drive and also be able to update the files based on interaction we had.

With drive scope we alarm users that we have unlimited access to their google drive and it's not a requirement either. We want to create a folder through our application and then let user copy/move all contents they want to search in this folder. I am struggling to list this folder though with any other scope other than full access. May be change some attribute on the folder?

The appDataFolder is invisible to users so we can't use that either.

Is there anyway we only ask for permission for above use case and not god access on their whole google drive? I know the short answer will be NO but I thought I should ask before I give up.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can use the `drive.file` scope to grant your application access only to files and folders created by itself, though files and folders **inside** a folder your application has access to do not inherit this property.*

#### More Information:

If only files created by the application are acceptable, then as per the Drive API documentation<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth)</sup>, the `drive.file` scope:

> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.

can be used. This is the recommended restricted scope, and has the URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

If the file hasn't been created by the application, then the user has to explicitly share the file with the application for this scope to be able to access it, for example using the 'open with' menu item and selecting your App.

Alternatively, you could use a service account within your App which the user can share the folder with - while this would require further implementation the service account would have no need to use a Drive scope as it would already have been granted access.

#### References:

- [Authenticate your users | Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth)
- [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)

Comment: It doesn't give you access on files created by users in the folder created by my application. Only files which are created by my application. So I get access to folder we have created because that we have created. We want users to be able to move all the files they want us to deal with to this folder outside the application so we can access them but we are unable to do so.

Comment: Yeah in which case unfortunately your assertion of no is correct - the application needs to have opened or created the files themselves to be able to do this. I have updated my answer.